# How to find the timestamp of when last commit statement was issued?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

I looked up this on the Internet and most discussions were about finding the time of last change made. In my case, I want to find the timestamp of when a COMMIT statement was issued for the last, by any user (schema).

Is there any particular way to query this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I want to find out whether I have forgotten to commit the last transaction I did with SQL*Plus. Of course I can do some SELECT statements to check whether update has been committed. But I was wondering if there's any quick way like "select last_commit_time from v$something"

Comment: The only way to do it, as far as I know, is to log it... if you're using SQL*Plus it normally autocommits when you exit though... if you haven't exited you can tell whether you've committed the session.

Comment: This query: `select scn_to_timestamp( dbms_flashback.get_system_change_number )
from dual;` gives a time of the last commit, however it is of no value, because ORACLE itself commits in the background from time to time, even if no user is logged into the database. If you know a table involved in your transaction, you can obtain a time of the last commit for this table using: `select scn_to_timestamp( max( ORA_ROWSCN ) ) from tablename`

Comment: Last two comments are helpful. Kordirko's comment looks more like an answer. Could you please post it an answer?

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to know, is whether the current SQL*Plus session has an open transaction, you can do that by selecting TADDR from V$SESSION.

Example:

```
SQL> create table testme(a number);

Table created.

SQL> select taddr from v$session where sid=(select sid from v$mystat where rownum=1);

TADDR
----------------


SQL> insert into testme values(1);

1 row created.

SQL> select taddr from v$session where sid=(select sid from v$mystat where rownum=1);

TADDR
----------------
0000007F50F86420

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select taddr from v$session where sid=(select sid from v$mystat where rownum=1);

TADDR
----------------


SQL>
```

IF TADDR is null, then there is no current transaction.

Hope that helps.